# First query execute on mysql is slow. 2nd on eexecute faster after first execution. why?

Tags: sql, mysql, innodb

I using a mysql 8.0 innodb table and run a query that joins multiple tables.
In the first pass, the query takes a lot of time to execute and if I run another condition on select with the same query, it runs very fast.

Why is that? and how can I optimize my queries to run fast on the first execution?

I tried customizing the parameters
innodb_buffer_pool_size
key_buffer_size
table_open_cache
But the probability of it happening is still there from my system

Comment: [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question)

Comment: *Why is that?* When you execute the first time then the server must read tables data from disk. When you execute one more time then some data (table data, indices) is already cached in the memory and does not need to be readed again. Compare your disk activity during 1st and 2nd executions..

Comment: *how can I optimize my queries to run fast on the first execution?* Warming up the cache (executing some fake queries which fills the caches) at the server start can be tried.

Comment: Please post TEXT results of  A) SELECT @@version_compile_os;  and B) SELECT @@version;   Welcome to SO.

Comment: TruongGiang      Even though your Question is Closed, If you could post the information requested on Oct 31 at 16:45, someone will help you.

Comment: To optimize the _first_ execution, let's see the query and `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  There are many techniques for optimizing; some may apply to _your_ query.